# Determining if $\sum_{n =3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/n}\cdot n\cdot \log(n)}$ diverges or converges.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

How would I show $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot n \cdot \log(n)}$ converges or diverges?

I want to say $n^{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot n \cdot \log(n) \cong n^{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$ converges but the $\dfrac{1}{n}$ doesn't help.

Comment: The $n^{1/n}$ does not matter. It converges to $1.$ For positive integers it is smaller than $2$

Comment: @WillJagy I know that, however I have to write a rigorous proof that the $n^{1/n}$ doesn't matter. EDIT: Thanks, that clarifies everything

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $n^{1/n}<2$ by induction, so $\dfrac{1}{n^{1+1/n}\log n}>\dfrac{1}{2n\log n}$ and it is known that $\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{1}{n\log n}=\infty$.